# No wifi connection after (partial) upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, 18.04, wireless, upgrade

I have tried to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 using Mobile data (Wifi).

After restarting the system my Wifi connection is not working.

System shows all available network connections, but is not able to connect. System shows "Network connection failed".

Now I am not able to complete the partial upgrade. Please guide me in this regard to complete the installation.

In Sortware Updater shows

"Not all updates can be installed
Run a partial upgrade, to install as many updates as possible.
This can be caused by:
A previous upgrade which didn't complete
Problems with some of the installed software
Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Normal changes of a pre-release version of Ubuntu"

Options showing :
Settings
Partial Upgrade
Continue

But Not able connect Wifi
"Connetion failed
Activation of network connection failed"
Message shows

Update information
Data files for some packages could not be downloaded
The folloring packages requested additional data downloading after package processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

This is a permanent failure that leaves these packages unsuable on your system. You may need to fix your internet connection, then remove and reminstall the packages to fix this problem.

Comment: What is the brand and model of your computer?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1259585/edit) to answer: Did the system really offer you a "Partial Upgrade?" If so, did you accept? Did the system disconnect before beginning the upgrade? During downloading? After downloading but during install? Did your system merely disconnect, or did it completely shut down or reboot during the upgrade? Or was the upgrade successful, uninterrupted, and complete before your reboot? These details will determine the advice we provide.